# Run virtualbox in other X session

Tags: virtualbox, xorg, session, fullscreen, mir

I'm running ubuntu on my laptop (host). Inside ubuntu, there is running one instance of virtualbox. (where is installed MS Windows). My idea is to run virtualbox in separate X session (something like multiuser).

If it is not clear, i'll try to explain...

When I want to visit tty1, I'll press CTRL+ALT+F1. To return to my Unity desktop, I'm gona use CTRL+ALT+F7... And here comes what I need. After pressing CTRL+ALT+F8 show fullscreen virtualbox windows system, just to switch as ttys..

I am using Ubuntu 14.10. I have wasted hours by using google to find some solution, but my biggest prolem is I cannot name the problem.

Comment: Have a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_program_in_separate_X_display and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1806161